# Update failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call: []

Tags: trigger

I am getting below error, can you please suggest what could be the reason?

> Update failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call: []

```
trigger AgreementUpdateFromApprovalRequest on Apttus_Approval__Approval_Request__c (after insert , after update)
{
Map<id,Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c> agreementToUpdate_map = new Map<id,Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c>();
    for (Apttus_Approval__Approval_Request__c  nRecord : trigger.new) {
        Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c agreementToUpdateObj = new Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c();
        agreementToUpdateObj.Id = nRecord.Apttus_Approval__Parent_Agreement__c;
        agreementToUpdateObj.Last_Activity_Date_Time__c = nRecord.LastModifiedDate;
        agreementToUpdateObj.Last_Activity_by_User__c = nRecord.LastModifiedByid;
        if(!agreementToUpdate_Map.containskey(nRecord.Apttus_Approval__Parent_Agreement__c))
        {
            agreementToUpdate_Map.put(nRecord.Apttus_Approval__Parent_Agreement__c,agreementToUpdateObj);
        }
}

        if(agreementToUpdate_map.values().size()>0){
            update agreementToUpdate_Map.values();

    }        
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to actually `insert` new records? If so just change `update` to `insert`.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that not all `Apttus_Approval__Approval_Request__c` have a value for `Apttus_Approval__Parent_Agreement__c`. So, this statement places a null ID in the object to be updated:

```
agreementToUpdateObj.Id = nRecord.Apttus_Approval__Parent_Agreement__c;
```

rework your logic to only update parent records if the `trigger.new` record(s) actually have a parent